# Select Only Rows With Different Value of Both Rows

Tags: mysql

I have tbl_user, tbl_friendship

```
- tbl_user
uid username
1     Joun
2     Bun
3     Meu
4     Nux
5     Zii

- tbl_friendship
friend_1 friend_2 status
1        2        1
1        3        1
1        4        0
5        1        1
2        3        1
```

friend_1 and friend_2 is FK to tbl_user.uid

status 1 mean friend_1 and friend_2 are friends.
status 0 mean friend_1 sends friend_2 a request but friend_2 is not accept it.

How to show all user who are friends with user Joun (uid 1). The expected result is :

```
2
3
5
```

I tried

```
SELECT friend_1, friend_2 FROM tbl_friendship
WHERE status = 1 AND friend_1 = 1 OR friend_2 = 1
```

result :

```
friend_1 friend_2
1        2
1        3
5        1
```

Comment: Expected output `2,3,5` why not `1`?

Comment: @Sadikhasan I want to show friends of user 1. Not user 1 itself

Comment: Oke, this is duplicate because i dont know how to ask this.

Comment: I can't give answer because your question mark as duplicate by `Barmar`

Comment: Use This:     (SELECT `friend_1` as friend FROM `tbl_friendship` WHERE `friend_2`=1 and status=1) UNION (SELECT `friend_2` as friend FROM `tbl_friendship` WHERE `friend_1`=1 and status=1) order by friend